# "No active and enabled video connection" when trying to use AVCapturePhotoOutput

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, avcapture, avcapturephotooutput

I need a way to take photos programmatically from a macOS app and I am using `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to achieve this.

First I initialize the camera with

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    fileprivate var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    fileprivate var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    fileprivate var captureConnection: AVCaptureConnection!
    fileprivate var cameraDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
    fileprivate var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.prepareCamera()
        self.startSession()
    }
    
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        self.capturePhoto()
    }
}
```

```swift
extension ViewController {
    func startSession() {
        if let videoSession = captureSession {
            if !videoSession.isRunning {
                videoSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopSession() {
        if let videoSession = captureSession {
            if videoSession.isRunning {
                videoSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func capturePhoto() {
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
    }
    
    fileprivate func prepareCamera() {
        self.photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        
        if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
            for device in devices {
                if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaType.video) {
                    cameraDevice = device
                    
                    if cameraDevice != nil  {
                        do {
                            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)
                            
                            
                            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                                captureSession.addInput(input)
                            }
                            
                            if let previewLayer = self.previewLayer {
                                if ((previewLayer.connection?.isVideoMirroringSupported) != nil) {
                                    previewLayer.connection?.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
                                    previewLayer.connection?.isVideoMirrored = true
                                }
                                
                                previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
                                view.layer = previewLayer
                                view.wantsLayer = true
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sample buffer delegate", attributes: []))
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I get

```
2021-06-02 14:15:55.673352+0300 LenzDataUtil[29276:1484981] [General] *** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] No active and enabled video connection
2021-06-02 14:15:55.675900+0300 LenzDataUtil[29276:1484981] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204ec5bf __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20224bbb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   AVFCapture                          0x00007fff378c4c74 -[AVCapturePhotoOutput_Tundra preparedPhotoSettingsArray] + 0
    3   LenzDataUtil                        0x0000000108e1b645 $s12LenzDataUtil14ViewControllerC12capturePhotoyyF + 245
    4   LenzDataUtil                        0x0000000108e1b4be $s12LenzDataUtil14ViewControllerC6buttonyyypF + 222
    5   LenzDataUtil                        0x0000000108e1b6d0 $s12LenzDataUtil14ViewControllerC6buttonyyypFTo + 80
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff22db7b0b -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 288
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff22db79af -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff22db78e1 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff22db77e8 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 171
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff22db772e -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 96
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff22db4813 NSControlTrackMouse + 1820
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff22db40cf -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 130
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff22db3f96 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 697
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff22db32cd -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 722
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff22db16ce -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 4961
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d20fb8 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2594
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d20376 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 347
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d1e784 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 352
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff22ff7979 -[NSApplication _handleEvent:] + 65
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff22b8769e -[NSApplication run] + 623
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff22b5b85c NSApplicationMain + 816
    22  LenzDataUtil                        0x0000000108e1d154 $sSo21NSApplicationDelegateP6AppKitE4mainyyFZ + 36
    23  LenzDataUtil                        0x0000000108e1d11e $s12LenzDataUtil11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
    24  LenzDataUtil                        0x0000000108e1d1d9 main + 41
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20394f3d start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

after triggering `self.capturePhoto()` with a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to find a working example of how to use AVCapturePhotoOutput from Swift.

The following code was taken from [Dan Clipca's](https://github.com/dclipca) GitHub project, [AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://github.com/dclipca/AVCapturePhotoOutput):

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import AVFoundation
import Cocoa
import AppKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    // MARK: - Properties
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var captureConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
    var cameraDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var mouseLocation: NSPoint { NSEvent.mouseLocation }
    
    // MARK: - LyfeCicle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        prepareCamera()
        startSession()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UtilityFunctions
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        moveMouseToRandomScreenPoint()
        capturePhoto()
    }
    
    func startSession() {
        if let videoSession = captureSession {
            if !videoSession.isRunning {
                videoSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopSession() {
        if let videoSession = captureSession {
            if videoSession.isRunning {
                videoSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }
    
    internal func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
        print("willBeginCaptureFor")
    }
    
    internal func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        print("didFinishProcessingPhoto")
        print(photo)
    }
    
    func capturePhoto() {
        print(captureConnection?.isActive)
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
    }
    
    func prepareCamera() {
        photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
        previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        do {
            let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.front)
            let cameraDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices[0]
            let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cameraDevice)
            captureSession!.beginConfiguration()
            if captureSession!.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                print("Adding videoInput to captureSession")
                captureSession!.addInput(videoInput)
            } else {
                print("Unable to add videoInput to captureSession")
            }
            if captureSession!.canAddOutput(photoOutput!) {
                captureSession!.addOutput(photoOutput!)
                print("Adding videoOutput to captureSession")
            } else {
                print("Unable to add videoOutput to captureSession")
            }
            captureConnection = AVCaptureConnection(inputPorts: videoInput.ports, output: photoOutput!)
            captureSession!.commitConfiguration()
            if let previewLayer = previewLayer {
                if ((previewLayer.connection?.isVideoMirroringSupported) != nil) {
                    previewLayer.connection?.automaticallyAdjustsVideoMirroring = false
                    previewLayer.connection?.isVideoMirrored = true
                }
                previewLayer.frame = view.bounds
                view.layer = previewLayer
                view.wantsLayer = true
            }
            captureSession!.startRunning()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```